# Strange behavior of "for ... in ..." construct

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have a div with 4 checkbox. Then I run the following javascript:

```
var elements = document.getElementById('myDiv').getElementsByTagName('input');
alert(elements.length); // output: 4
for (element in elements) {
    alert(element);
}
alert('finish!');
```

After the 4, I get the following alerts, in that order:

```
0
1
2
3
item
namedItem
length
finish!
```

The numbers from 0 to 3 are the indexes of elements. But what does 'item', 'namedItem' and 'length' mean here?

Comment: Don't use `for ... in ...` to loop over arrays, `for ... in ...` iterate over object properties, not indexes, so you will get all the properties of an array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: Avoid `for...in` like the plague.

Comment: @Shan ...unless you want to iterate over properties of objects...

Comment: Although getElementsByTagName does not return a "real" array - for most pusposes it is still an array. So refer to questions listed in comments for more information on why it is a bad idea to iterate over arrays with for in.

Comment: Even using almost the same words of "Strange behavior in Javascript enhanced for…in loop", this question didn't show up in the list of "Questions that may already have your answer"...

Comment: @deceze: there are much better ways and less random. Looping over `Object.keys(obj)` for example.

Comment: @Shan "Less random"? What does that mean? What are those "better ways"?

Comment: @deceze if you start using a library changing the prototype of built-in types, `for...in` will get extra properties and stuff. That's unpredictable behaviour, so "random" for me.

Comment: @Shan That's why you must use `.hasOwnProperty` when using `for..in`. Still curios what those "better ways" are then.

Comment: @deceze Looping over [Object.keys(obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for example. And it also works on arrays.

Comment: @Shan Yes, that's a possibility, but it's also possibly slower, due to having to loop twice (once to return the property names, then to actually enumerate them). `for..in .. if .hasOwnProperty` is the canonical established vanilla Javascript idiom...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document.getElementById('myDiv').getElementsByTagName('input')` does not return a true array. It is an `array like` object. So functions like `forEach` and `map` doesn't exist on it. And `for ... in ...` got a weird behavior with it.

You can convert it into a true array with `slice` :

```
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('myDiv').getElementsByTagName('input'));
```

Comment: I used the old for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) instead of slice. But thanks for explaining the "array like" stuff.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_form_elements.asp
As seen in this link you're outputing the properties and methods of your input elements.

Comment: I don't understand what the question has to do with select element?

Comment: Well me netiher but those three things he was wondering about:
item
namedItem
length

Comment: The edited answer is more to the point, so I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score -1):

`elements` in your code is not javascript array, its an array-like object. It is actually HTMLCollection which has some additional enumerable properties.

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object.

see [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Comment: Could you expand a bit? It's link-only as of now, so -1.

Comment: Now it's just ill-duping another answer...